# mootools | toggler event

Tags: javascript, click, toggle, mootools, dom-events

I have mootools code:

```
document.getElements('.toggler').addEvent('click', function(e){

var target  = this.getChildren('i');
console.log(target);

if (target.hasClass('icon-minus')) {
   console.log('hasclass - minus'); 
   target.addClass('icon-plus').removeClass('icon-minus');
   this.getNext('div').hide();
} else {    
   console.log('hasclass - plus');
   target.addClass('icon-minus').removeClass('icon-plus');
   this.getNext('div').show();
}                           
});
```

My HTML layout:

```
<div class="filter">
   <sup class="toggler">
      <i class="icon-minus"></i>
   </sup>
</div>
```

But if I click on the toggler I will get:

```
1: Object[i.icon-minus]
hasclass - minus
2: Object[i.icon-plus]
hasclass - minus
3: Object[i.icon-plus]
hasclass - minus
```

This is an error!
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternative way to write would be:

```
document.getElements('.toggler').addEvent('click', function(e){
    e && e.stop();
    // the i and the div won't change. only get them from DOM once.
    var i = this.retrieve('i', this.getElement('i')),
        next = this.retrieve('next', this.getNext('div')),
        // keep state in storage also, no need to query dom all the time.
        isCollapsed = this.retrieve('state', i.hasClass('icon-plus'));

    // based upon current state (which we don't need in DOM after the first time)
    // calls either hide or show dynamically.
    next[['hide', 'show'][+isCollapsed]]();
    // all we want is to swap the classes, use toggleClass. 
    i.toggleClass('icon-plus').toggleClass('icon-minus');
    // save new state
    this.store('state', !isCollapsed);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/3ZY9Q/

this minimizes your dom lookups and works from memory (element storage) - and it also removes if/then/else code complexity.

Comment: Interesting alternative and smart use of storage! `+1` I would go for this one. Using the storage is actually better than relying on classes I have read.

Comment: it's a micro-optimisation. unless you click 1000 times in 1 second on the toggler and use IE8, you won't _notice_ a difference. so it's pretty much developer fun. your version is something they will probably understand much easier. :)

Comment: Well, nice for me to read/learn in a problem I studied a bit. Anyway besides the developer fun it does seem your __[storage approach](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mootools-users/OG7mp-lpAU8)__ is better.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `.getChildren()` you get no a element but a Mootools collection. A array.

Looks like this:

```
[i.icon-minus, $family: function, $constructor: function,// etc
```

If you do 
`console.log(target.hasClass('icon-minus'))` you get:

```
[false, $family: function, $constructor: function, each: function, // etc
```

Which means the `.hasClass` works but its boolean is inside a collection.

So, my suggestion is:

**If** there is just one `i` inside each `.toggler` use:

```
var target  = this.getFirst('i');
//or
var target  = this.getElement('i');
```

**If** there are several `i` inside `.toggler` use:

```
target.each(function(thisElement){

    if (thisElement.hasClass('icon-minus')) {
        thisElement.addClass('icon-plus').removeClass('icon-minus');
        this.getNext('div').hide();
    } else {
        thisElement.addClass('icon-minus').removeClass('icon-plus');
        this.getNext('div').show();
    }
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xX8Fp/)